# How to set value to XML element with Set-body Policy of API Management

Tags: xml, soap, azure-api-management, azure-policy, xmlelement

In this case, I want to get an accessTokenTest first, then I will create an SOAP request by using this accessTokenTest. But I have a problem with adding this accessTokenTest to an XML element. Everything fine except filling this value into XML.

```html
<set-variable name="accessTokenTest" value="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["ABCOauth"]).Body.As<JObject>()["access_token"].ToString())" />
<set-body template="liquid">
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://servicxxxx>
    <soap:Body>
     <GetUsersxxx>
      <userIds>
{% for item in body.getUserxxxx.userIds -%}
<string>{{item}}</string>
{% endfor -%}
</userIds>
      <credentials>
       <Client>{{body.getUsersByUserId.credentials.client}}</Client>
       <AccessToken>(string)context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("accessTokenTest")</AccessToken>
      </credentials>
     </GetUsersxxxx>
    </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>
</set-body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using liquid templates in the [`set-body` policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#using-liquid-templates-with-set-body), there is a different syntax for accessing the `context` object as shown in the docs, similar to what you have used for the client value.

In your case, the policy would have to look something like this

```xml
<set-variable name="accessTokenTest" value="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["ABCOauth"]).Body.As<JObject>()["access_token"].ToString())" />
<set-body template="liquid">
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://servicxxxx>
    <soap:Body>
      <GetUsersxxx>
        <userIds>
{% for item in body.getUserxxxx.userIds -%}
          <string>{{item}}</string>
{% endfor -%}
        </userIds>
        <credentials>
          <Client>{{body.getUsersByUserId.credentials.client}}</Client>
          <AccessToken>{{context.Variables["accessTokenTest"]}}</AccessToken>
        </credentials>
      </GetUsersxxxx>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</set-body>
```